# Exception caught by TextFormField

Tags: flutter

**I have an exception when upgrade flutter when write in TextFormField any word  appeare**
════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Exception caught by services library
Stack Overflow
════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Flutter plugin version 50.0.1
Dart plugin version 193.7547

what made this exception I don't understand this is code

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBarWithBack(context, getTranslated(context, "addCustomer")),
      drawer: DrawerList(context),
      body: LoadingOverlay(
          child: Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: FormUI(),
          ),
          isLoading: _isLoading,
          opacity: 0.2,
          color: Style.MainColor,
          progressIndicator: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Style.MainColor),))
    );}
```

```
Widget FormUI() {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
         // margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric( horizontal: 35.0 ,vertical: 30.0),
          child:  Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child:Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric( horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 20.0),
              child:Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  //Name
                   TextFormField(
                        controller: nameController,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return getTranslated(context,'name_Validation');
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        cursorColor: Style.SecondryColor,
                        decoration:  InputDecoration(
                          labelText: getTranslated(context, 'clientName'),
                        ),
                        onEditingComplete: () {
                          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                        }
                    ),

                  //Phone
                       TextFormField(
                        controller: phoneController,
                        cursorColor: Style.SecondryColor,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                        decoration:  InputDecoration(
                         // hintText: 'ex@ex.com',
                          labelText: getTranslated(context, 'phone'),
                        ),
                        onEditingComplete: () {
                          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                        }
                    ),

                  // save
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0.h),

                    child:  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0.h),
                      decoration: Style.BoxDecorationWithRadius,
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Text(
                          getTranslated(context, 'save'),
                          style: Style.Header5,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        onTap: ()async {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            showLoading();
                            var result= await AddCustomer(context,nameController.text,phoneController.text);
                            hideLoading();
                            if(result == true)
                            {
                              Navigator.pushNamed(context, homeRoute);
                            }
                          }

                        },
                      ), ),  ),  ],),),), ),], ),);}
```

Comment: SUGGESTION: try wrapping your Scaffold with MaterialApp: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66240762/421195

Comment: Could you show the exception message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.